# ionic 2 InAppBrowser url not opening

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, inappbrowser

I am using Ionic 2 and trying to open an external link with cordova InAppBrowser.

```
launch(url) {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system", "location=yes");
    console.log("link viewed");
  });
}
```

However, this does not open a link when I am testing the app on my phone. Furthermore, it returns this in the console `Your current usage of the InAppBrowser plugin is depreciated as of ionic-native@1.3.8. Please check the Ionic Native docs for the latest usage details.`

When i change it to this `cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system", "location=yes");` it returns with a syntax error saying cannot find `cordova`

In the browser `window.open(url, "_system", "location=yes");` works fine.

Anyone know the updated way to get the InAppBrowser to open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few hours and looking deep into the documents I found out the reason.

```
launch(url) { 
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
     new InAppBrowser(url, "_system", "location=yes");
     console.log("link viewed");
   });
}
```

Comment: yeah, I only found the old syntax as ionic2 was previously still in development

Comment: Good work Keep it up ... Please Improve your answer then i will delete mine one